# The modal is not working in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a website by using Bootstrap and when i tried to use modal it didn't work me! I mean it didn't pop-up. I've searched every single solution but couldn't solve it. Then I found

Best Regards

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type"button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Subscribe to our Mailing List</h4>
            </div><!--modal header-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Simply enter your name and email! As a thank you for joining us, we're going to give you one of our best-selling courses, <em>for free!</em></p>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-name">Your first name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribe-name" placeholder="Your first name">
                    </div><!--form group-->
                </form><!--form-->
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe-email">and your email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="and your email">
                    </div><!--form group-->
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Subscribe!">
                </form><!--form-->
                <hr>
                <p><small>By providing your email you consent to receiving occosional promotional emails & newsletter. <br>No Spam. Just good stuff. We respect your privacy & you may unsubscribe at any time.</small></p>
            </div><!--modal-body-->
        </div><!--modal-content-->
    </div><!--modal-dialog-->
 </div><!--modal-->



<!--BOOTSTRAP CORE JAVASCRIPT
   ==========================-->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Then I found this code and added my "main.js" file then it worked fine but after this when I use my webpage on phone and click on the right top it opened modal instead of opening navbar. Here is the image!

[You can find what I meant here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6SWa.png)

PS: Sorry if i make any misspelling!

```
$('button').click(function(){
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Where is the `button` (opener of the modal) ?

Comment: Do you mean this one?

<section id="optin">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
       <p class="lead"><strong>Subscribe to our mailing list.</strong> We'll send something speacial as a thank you</p>
      </div><!--col-->
      
      <div class="col-sm-4">
       <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModel">Click here to Subscribe</button>
      </div><!--col-->
     </div><!--row-->
    </div><!--CONTAINER-->
   </section><!--OPTIN-->

Comment: Its working. Check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9n9pfhe5/)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman even though it is working there it is not correct. The event is bound to all "button" element which is incorrect and hence the author is facing issue

Comment: @GörkemÇakır please check if following fixes your issue.

Comment: Yeah it's working but when I click another button also it opens same window. :) Also I gave and specific ID to this button and it works totally fine for me now! By the way thanks for help!

Comment: @TechBreak yes, I know but the question was that modal is not opening. Not functioning properly because OP has bind events to all buttons is another problem.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman author added this description i suppose.

"then it worked fine but after this when I use my webpage on phone and click on the right top it opened modal instead of opening navbar. "

Comment: @GörkemÇakır please accept my answer if that helped you :)

Comment: @TechBreak ok I skipped this part. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always look for 'specific' element instead of using 'common' elements in your DOM.

You current code fail as you have bound a click event on 'button' element which means on any 'button' element of your DOM you want to show up a modal.

What you should do is following,

```
// this will add click event on only button with specific id i.e. button_id
$('button#button_id').click(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

or

```
// this will add click event on only button with specific class i.e. button_class
$('button.button_class').click(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Also main thing to look here is why your modal is not opened without this js snippet you added.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare it in global. `i.e. $('button')` . Instead, As @Bilal suggest, use the button with some class name or id.

```
$('button.classname').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Or

```
$('button#id-name').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```